# Extract names and covert to email addresses in R

Tags: r, character

I have the following string: "    John Andrew Thomas"(4 empty spaces before John) and I need to split and concat it so my output is "John@gmail.com;Andrew@gmail.com;Thomas@gmail.com", also I need to remove all whitespaces.

My best guess is:

```
test = unlist(lapply(names, strsplit, split = " ", fixed = FALSE))
paste(test, collapse = "@gmail.com")
```

but I get this as an output:

```
"@gmail.com@gmail.com@gmail.com@gmail.comJohn@gmail.comAndrew@gmail.comThomas"
```

Comment: You want to use `sep` instead of `collapse` in `paste`.

Comment: `"John Andrew Thomas" %>% strsplit(" ") %>% unlist %>% paste0("@gmail.com")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
names <- "    John Andrew Thomas"
test <- unlist(lapply(names, strsplit, split = " ", fixed = FALSE))
paste(test[test != ""],"@gmail.com",sep = "",collapse = ";")
```

A small tweak to your paste line will remove the extra spaces and separate the email addresses with a semicolon.

Output is the following:

```
[1] "John@gmail.com;Andrew@gmail.com;Thomas@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `stringr`, so we can use its `str_trim` function to deal with your leading whitespace, and assuming your string is `x`:

```
library(stringr)

paste(sapply(str_split(str_trim(x), " "), function(i) sprintf("%s@gmail.com", i)), collapse = ";")
```

And here's a piped version, so it's easier to follow:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x %>%
    # get rid of leading and trailing whitespace
    str_trim() %>%
    # make a list with the elements of the string, split at " "
    str_split(" ") %>%
    # get an array of strings where those list elements are added to a fixed chunk via sprintf
    sapply(., function(i) sprintf("%s@gmail.com", i)) %>%
    # concatenate the resulting array into a single string with semicolons
    paste(., collapse = ";")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `trimws` function of base R

```
paste0(unlist(strsplit(trimws(names)," ")),"@gmail.com",collapse = ";")
#[1] "John@gmail.com;Andrew@gmail.com;Thomas@gmail.com"
```

**Data**

```
names <- "    John Andrew Thomas"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea using `stringi`:

```
v <- "    John Andrew Thomas"
paste0(stringi::stri_extract_all_words(v, simplify = TRUE), "@gmail.com", collapse = ";")
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "John@gmail.com;Andrew@gmail.com;Thomas@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub()`, and a little creativity.

```
x <- "    John Andrew Thomas"

paste0(gsub(" ", "@gmail.com;", trimws(x)), "@gmail.com")
# [1] "John@gmail.com;Andrew@gmail.com;Thomas@gmail.com"
```

No packages, no loops, and no string splitting.